# initialCapacity in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I need to create an `ArrayList` and I know upfront that the max size for this array won't exceed more than 5 elements.

I wanted to know from the community whether initailCapacity specifying size as 5 will have any performance benefits.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(5);
```

or

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Which one is better?

Comment: There are several posts here on SO about this, plus information in the Java docs. So I'll just make this a comment: *yes*, this will most likely have performance benefits. Java has to initialize the ArrayList with some size; if it chose something lower than 5, it would have to reallocate later, wasting CPU cycles. If it chose something larger, it might be wasting memory.

Comment: Don't forget/underestimate the `LinkedList`,

Comment: @JoopEggen you mean, because a `LinkedList` with five entries does already consume far more memory than an `ArrayList` with its default capacity (of ten)?

Comment: @Holger I meant LinkedList is maybe too rarely taken in consideration. 5 may be the general maximum, maybe 80% at most 1, or such. Then a linked list might be more suitable - I thought.

Comment: @JoopEggen what’s often overlooked, is the option to use the specialized immutable lists, i.e. `Collections.emptyList()`, `Collections.singletonList(…)`, or Java 9‘s `List.of(…)`, which currently has specializations for zero, one, and two elements. As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57775030/2711488), an `ArrayList` with default initial capacity, to which has never added to, won’t have a backing array, so `LinkedList` will only shine when having exactly one element but needing mutability.

Answer (score 4):

If you do expect that the list will usually be populated with at least some elements (but no more than 5), then yes, setting an initial capacity of 5 will likely be the most efficient way to go.

## Lazy instantiation of backing array

However, if the most common / expected case is that **not even a single item gets added to the list**, then the constructor without any specified initial capacity may be more efficient. This is because (assuming a somewhat recent JDK version is used) the ArrayList will not yet allocate any backing array at all, but just use a reference shared among all empty, default-constructed ArrayLists. It will only actually allocate memory once you start adding items to it.

When you add your first element to the `ArrayList`, a new backing array is created. That new array defaults to a size of ten.

---

To see that a shared reference to a backing array is initially used, you can look at OpenJDK's github for example, and you can find the implementation of the no-args constructor [here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/9d764ee48ee7c2e7be7a25aee2ed7bed2fcd2000/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L169). It looks as follows:

```
public ArrayList() {
    this.elementData = DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
}
```

That reference that the backing array (`elementData`) is assigned to is declared higher up in the file as follows:

```
/**
 * Shared empty array instance used for default sized empty instances. We
 * distinguish this from EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA to know how much to inflate when
 * first element is added.
 */
private static final Object[] DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};
```

**This does not only happen in OpenJDK**, but also in Oracle's JDK. At least, it does in the version I have on my computer right here. I don't know if there are any easy-to-find links to Oracle's source code though, OpenJDK source code is easier to find online.

Comment: Oracle JDK is built from the same sources as OpenJDK, so the code you found applies to both.

Answer (score 1):

From ArrayList.java

```
/**
 * Default initial capacity.
 */
private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
```

The default capacity (used when you don't provide one) is ten. So specifying the size of five will mean less memory gets used.

If you know that you'll only ever have a certain number, perhaps an Array will be a more lightweight choice.

Comment: Look at the no-args ArrayList constructor in JDK8, its default capacity *is not* 10, it's actually 0.

Comment: Agreed, but as soon as any item is added, the size will be bumped to 10; look at ensureCapacityInternal

Comment: Yes, unless you're attempting to add a collection to the ArrayList, in which case it will use the larger of the two of 10 vs the incoming collection's size. Either way, it's forcing an expansion of the underlying array which isn't done when you specify an explicit initial capacity, so will be less performant. That said, the difference is likely negligible for the vast majority of applications.

Comment: @JonK when using the default constructor, no array will be created, so the first “expansion” is not different to creating the array right in the constructor when an explicit capacity has been given. So there’s no performance difference, unless the capacity of ten is insufficient (and your first operation isn’t `addAll`).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the use case. Suppose if you already know that a specific number of objects(in this case string objects) are going to be stored for sure, then if you would specify the size of the ArrayList while creating it would allocate the memory at that step.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(5);
```

Then once the elements are filled the size of the ArrayList will expand dynamically as you add more objects. Suppose if you are going to add 50 elements to the ArrayList for sure, then specify the initial capacity as 50 which would result in allocating that much space. This would be a more efficient approach as you wont be dynamically allocating the memory up to 50 elements after initialization. Allocating memory as the ArrayList expands will affect the performance. At the same time if you specify a large initial size then you are wasting valuable memory space.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, it will improvethe performance, as not much memory default of 10 will be occupied

Comment: The initial capacity of an ArrayList when it's not explicitly specified is zero, not 10. 10 is the default amount that it will then expand by when you try and add the first element to it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will improve performance but only by a tiny amount.

Good practice would be to set the list to a specific length if you know it will always be that long, but such uses tend to be rare so shouldn't be a common issue.

Furthermore, if it is a 5 member list then you will probably be better off just making a new object with 5 fields. This will make handling this data easier and faster as won't need to search the list.